# How can i turn BASIC algorithm into javascript?

Tags: javascript, basic

Do you remember the days when BASIC-S was still used?
I was wondering how can I translate this

```
10 LET a=0
20 LET b=10
30 PRINT a+b
40 LET a=b
50 GOTO 20
```

into javascript, jquery or something that I can use...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Language are generally interchangeable..

```
var a=0;

do
{
   var b = 10;
   document.write(a+b);
   a=b;
} while(0)
```